# Need help with warning,Error : 1287,Setting user variable within expression is deprecated

Tags: mysql, warning

I have a simple table named `product_images` defined as:

```
FieldType   Null    Key Default Extra
image_id    int NO  PRI     
product_id  int NO  PRI     
image_url   varchar(255)    NO          
public_id   varchar(225)    YES
```

Whenever an image is deleted I just want to reset the `image_id` of same `product_id` of my table.

For example:I have 5 images with 1,2,3,4,5.
Now after deletion of the 2nd image I am left with 1,3,4,5.
So I wish to fix their numbering after deletion to 1,2,3,4.

For this,the query I have used is:

```
SET @row_number := 0;
UPDATE product_images
SET image_id = (@row_number := @row_number + 1)
WHERE product_id = ?
ORDER BY image_id;
```

And I am getting this warning :

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'. Rows matched: 2  Changed: 0  Warnings: 1

It works fine on MySQL Workbench, but when this query is executed through my ExpressJS server which is using mysql2 package to interact with the database,I get an error:1064 (Error in SQL syntax) and the query fails to execute.

In `package.json` the dependency version of "mysql2" is **^3.0.1**

The version of MySQL I am using is : **8.0.28**

Comment: There are now "windowing" functions for `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()`.  `@variables` make an Optimizer's job very hard.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about them .Thank you. I would really appreciate if someone creates the query using the windowing function.